# Synonym von »die wichtigen Sachen im Leben«

Tags: synonym

Wie kann man »die wichtigsten Sachen im Leben«, also etwa Freundschaft, Gesundheit usw. besser ausdrücken? Zum Beispiel im folgenden Satz:

> Diese Menschen wissen *die wichtigen Sachen* im Leben zu schätzen.

Comment: Gar nicht? Den Begriff "die wirklich wichtigen Dinge im Leben" verstehen wohl die meisten Leute, so wie du es beschreibst.

Comment: @IDV Aber ist das nicht zu banal?

Comment: Würde es eher als "am zutreffendsten beschrieben" betiteln. Sicherlich geht es auch poetischer, würde aber eher weniger in einen normalen Text passen.

Comment: Google liefert über 2 Mio. Treffer für den Begriff. Vielleicht ist er banal, aber ich lese den Begriff oft und wie gesagt - die meisten verstehen, was damit gemeint ist.

Comment: Vielleicht so etwas wie 'Essentials' (die Essentials des Lebens, englisch ausgesprochen), oder die 'sine qua nons' (dürfte nur Bildungsbürgern verständlich sein) - beides geht aber möglicherweise in Richtung 'lebensnotwendig', das hat einein anderen Akzent. Für Frauen könnte man dichten: 'Kinder, Küche und keine Karriere' - leider gibt's da nichts Allgemeingültiges: 'für Familie, Freunde, Firma  dasein'... Vielleicht hat mal wer was Schönes erfunden, das ist dann aber schwer zu finden.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fast zu offensichtlich:

> die wichtigsten Dinge im Leben

"Dinge" ist hier besser als "Sachen". "Sachen" wäre recht alltagssprachlich und flappsig. "Dinge" klingt etwas seriöser, und das ist bei den wichtigsten Dingen im Leben ja angemessen.

Oder natürlich

> das Wichtigste im Leben